# Unable to get textfield value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I have an `invoice.jsp` page where I have to calculate some value in the textbox using jQuery.

In my invoice there is a quantity textbox. If the user enters the quantity then the calculated price should be calculated dynamically i.e `(total_subPrice= unit_price * quantity)` and shown in another textbox called "price".

Now my current output is like this:
[image]

I tried the code below to solve this issue, but my jQuery code is unable to get the `unitprice` textfield data. I don't know why. Please check my code below and suggest me a solution for it.

invoice.jsp

```
--------------------
--------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
      $('input[name^="quantity"]').change(function() {
        var unitprice = $(this).siblings('input[name^="unitprice"]').val();
        alert("Unit price check="+unitprice);
        //problem in this line. Unable to get the unit price
        $(this).siblings('input[name^="price"]').val($(this).val() * unitprice);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
..............................
..............................
<!--
  Here I am iterating through a list from my dabase using strus2 framework tags.
  And defined my  input field values in struts2 tag eg. `<s:textfield.../>`
  is the same as `<input type="text".../>
-->
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <s:iterator  value="#session.BOK" status="userStatus">
    <tr style="height: 10px;">
      <td width="65%" align="left"><s:property value="bookTitile"/></td>
      <td width="10%" align="left">
        <s:textfield name="unitprice" value="%{price}" size="4"/>
      </td>
      <td width="10%" align="center">
        <s:textfield name="quantity" value="%{quantity}" size="2" />
      </td>
      <td width="15%" align="center">
        <s:textfield value="%{price}" name="" size="6"></s:textfield>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
</table>
................................
................................
```

When I change any value in my quantity textbox, my alert box is showing "Unit price check=undefined". Please check my code and suggest any solution.

**Update: Generated html**

```
 inside loop {
  <tr style="height: 10px;">
    <td width="65%" align="left">book title display</td>
    <td width="10%" align="left">
      <input type="text" name="unitprice" value="%{price}" size="4"/>
    </td>
    <td width="10%" align="center">
      <input type="text" name="quantity" value="%{quantity}" size="2" />
    </td>
    <td width="15%" align="center">
      <input type="text" value="%{price}" name="" size="6"></s:textfield>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: @Ibu i updated check my above code once again at **Update: Generated html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working: http://jsbin.com/efinak/2/edit

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="quantity"]').change(function() {
      var unitprice = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="unitprice"]').val();
      $(this).parents('tr').find(' input[name="price"]').val($(this).val() * unitprice);

    });
});
```

Comment: as you suggested. if i am applying in my code then it is affecting all of my items. i.e if i change the quantity of one item then it is affecting all of the item in my invoice too. I want to reflect price only to those item,whose quantity is changed not to all. How can we do this?

Comment: Ashu please check the new ans with jsbin link.

Comment: Sorry jai. Still your answer is not giving accurate output. Sometime it is changing sometime,& sometime it is not changing with exact unit price.   it is conflicting with some other item .