# Unable to calculate textfield values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to get textfield value using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438570/unable-to-get-textfield-value-using-jquery)

I am trying to change the input field when users changes the quantity of items in a text field. Here I am iterating through my list from my database. Now I have to make an invoice for customer.

In my code, if I am changing the quantity of a single item, then it is affecting all the other items in the list. I want to change only the specific items, where its quantity has been changed.

The code below is giving me an error. It is changing all the items value on single change of item quantity.

My code: **(New Update)**

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){  
                $(function() {        
                   $('input[name="quantity"]').change(function() {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var unitprice = $tr.find('input[name^="unitprice"]').val();  
                    $tr.find('input[name^="price"]').val($(this).val() * unitprice);
                }); 
                var totalPrice = 0;
                $('input[name="price"]').each(function(){
                    totalPrice += parseFloat(this.value);
                    $('[name=subtotal]').val(totalPrice);
                });
            }); 
        }); 
        </script>
         ..................
         ..................
         <tr>
            <td height="65%" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <s:iterator  value="#session.BOK" status="userStatus">
                        <tr style="height: 10px;"> 
                            <td width="65%" align="left"><s:property value="bookTitile"/></td> 
                            <td width="10%" align="left"><s:textfield name="unitprice" value="%{price}" size="4"/></td>
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><s:textfield name="quantity" value="1" size="2"/></td>  
                            <td width="15%" align="center"><s:textfield name="price" value="%{price}" size="6"></s:textfield> </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </s:iterator>  
                </table>   
                </td>
            </tr> 
              <tr>
                   <td height="1%" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                          <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                       <tr style="height: 10px;"> 
                                           <td width="100%" align="right" colspan="5">   
                                                <s:textfield name="subtotal"  size="5"> </s:textfield>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr> 
                           </table>  
                 </td>
          </tr>
```

The output looks like this image:

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the rendered output (the HTML) of that server-side script?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(function() {` Why?

Comment: @undefined Because i guess my code will work fine on page loads. I don't know much about jquery . I just gave a try. Please help me

Comment: @user1726508 Sorry, I wasn't here, it seems that the problem has been solved :)

Comment: @undefined Yes that problem is solved. Now i have a small problem. I want to add all the price values into one textfield called as subtotal as shown in my invoice image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {        
        $('input[name="quantity"]').change(function() {
            var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var unitprice = $tr.find('input[name^="unitprice"]').val();  
            $tr.find('input[name^="price"]').val($(this).val() * unitprice);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Update :** This the function that will return the total caculated price. Use it as per need.

```
function calculateBasket() {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    $('input[name="price"]').each(function(){
        totalPrice += parseFloat(this.value);
    });

    return totalPrice;
}
```

Comment: Thanks kundan. Now i want to new implementation. Please see my above invoice image. There is a textbox which counts the total of the sum of price. and also i have another textbox for specifying discount which reduces the price from the total sum of all price. How can i implement this for my above invoice?

Comment: what happen? You will not help?

Comment: I was trying. With your new code. But the total sum value is not setting in my new textfield `subtotal` . I updated my new code above. Please check it and suggest me a solution for it.

Comment: no problem.You don't do this. I solved this by myself.