# how to calculate values from one text box and set it to another textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to get textfield value using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438570/unable-to-get-textfield-value-using-jquery)

i have a invoice where i am iterating values from a list. There i have  textbox named `subtotal` , this textbox holds some number. And another textbox named `discountamt` ,in this textbox user will enter discount  in number,which will be calated as `discountamt percentage subtotal` .i.e(`discountamt % subtotal`) eg. 10% of subtotal.
And the calculated amount should reduce from subtotal and should set in anther textbox named `overalltotal` .

Please see my below image which shows how my output should be...
 [image]

Below is my code, where i am trying to implement this

```
 <tr>
           <td height="1%" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                               <tr style="height: 10px;"> 
                                   <td width="100%" align="right" colspan="5" style="font-weight: b"> 
                                       Sub Total. <s:textfield name="subtotal" value=" "  size="5"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                  </td>
                               </tr> 
                   </table>  
         </td>
      </tr> 
         <tr>
           <td height="1%" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                               <tr style="height: 10px;"> 
                                   <td width="100%" align="right" colspan="5"> 
                                          Discount:<sj:textfield name="discountamt"  size="1"  placeholder=" %"/>  
                                  </td>
                               </tr> 
                   </table>  
         </td>
      </tr> 

      <tr>
           <td height="1%" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                               <tr style="height: 10px;"> 
                                   <td width="100%" align="right" colspan="5" style="font-weight: bolder;">
                                   <s:set var="total" value="%{0}" />   
                                       Over All Total Amount: <s:textfield name="overalltotal  size="4"></s:textfield>  
                                  </td>
                               </tr> 
                   </table>  
         </td>
      </tr>
```

**UPDATE Correct Answer:**

```
       $('input[name="discountamt"]').keyup(function() 
                { 
                     var disamount=$('[name=discountamt]').val();
                     var linetotal = $('[name=subtotal]').val();  
                     var priceafterdisc=linetotal-(((disamount)/100)*linetotal);   
                    $('[name=overalltotal]').val(priceafterdisc); 
               });
```

Please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: Forgive the impertinence, but why are you allowing your users to set everything  (i.e., because it's in an input field, what prevents them from changing the price or line total of `book title Two` to `0.00`, or from setting a `discount` of `100%`)? Also, since you're apparently calculating client-side, what event should trigger the calculation?

Comment: Please stop asking essentially the same question over and over and over. Take a step back and learn about the environment you're in.

Comment: @DaveNewton Finally i will delete all the same question and remain only one which are good.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes you are correct. Now i will try to do it by myself. By asking with others i will not learn quickly. Now here after you will not see more question from my side. i will do it by myself.

Comment: @pets this is an application software. Only the owner of the bookshop can handle the invoice page for generting invoice Not the user. I just simply mention their user in my question.

Comment: To the OP, please make note of the answers below.  The one with the most up-votes gave you what you asked... how to do this _"using jQuery"_.  But the accepted answer is a little sloppy... it's done with plain JavaScript mixed with jQuery.  IMHO, the _best_ answer gets accepted, not the first.

Comment: @Sparky672 Yes i got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Html:

```
<input name="box1" id="box1" type="text">
<input name="box2" id="box2" type="text">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#box2').val($('#box1').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change element `name='whatever'` with `id='whatever'`

eg: `<s:textfield name="overalltotal"  size="4"></s:textfield>`
change to: `<s:textfield id="overalltotal"  size="4"></s:textfield>`